# javascript not displaying table values html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, qtip2

I'm creating a JavaScript application that when you hover the mouse a small window pops up displaying information about the value displayed in the cell. The function is shown bellow. However, when I load the page, nothing is shown when I hover the mouse over the cell, although when I run that function from firebug's terminal, it starts working as supposed.
Why ideas why?

```
$(document).ready(function()
        {
            $('#mytable td').qtip({
                content : {
                    text : function(api){
                        return "Time spend: " + $(this).html();
                    }
                },
                position : {
                    my : 'top left',
                    target : 'mouse',
                    viewport : $(window),       //keep it on-screen at all time if possible
                    adjust : {
                        x : 10, y : 10
                    }
                },
                hide : {
                    fixed : true                // Helps to prevent the tooltip from hiding occassionaly when tracking!
                },
                style : 'ui-tooltip-shadow'
            });
        });
```

and the HTML

```
<div id="mytable">
<table id="mytable" border="1px">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td style="background-color: rgb(0, 191, 255);">1</td>
<td style="background-color: rgb(0, 191, 255);">1</td>
<td style="background-color: rgb(0, 191, 255);">1</td>
```

This is just a sample of the table. The table itself is huge (a heatmap)

Comment: Did you close the HTML tags properly in your actual HTML file? Which version of jQuery and the qTip plugin are you using?

Comment: @Phil. Yes, that's only a sample of the table. The table itself it's huge.

Comment: @Phil I'm using `Jquery 1.7.2`, and `qtip` is the latest one. I downloaded yesterday.

Comment: I thought I just reproduced this problem. (I used the latest nightly build of qTip2) Then I found out I forgot to include the stylesheet qTip2 came with. :( Have Firebug open, when you hover your mouse over the cells, do you see qTip2's elements near the end of `</body>`?

Comment: @philippe Do you have the same problem in other browsers?

Comment: @beanland. Yes, in `Firefox`, `Explorer` and `Chrome`

Comment: @Phil in the `<head>` I did include 
`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://localhost/heatmap/css/jquery.qtip.css">`
`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://localhost/heatmap/css/main.css">`
Also, when I hover the mouse over, I can't see anything associated with `qTip2`

Comment: @beanland, Yes, I do have the same problem

Answer (score 0):

Please add overwrite and show properties to it and see if it works.

For example:

```
$(this).qtip({
      overwrite: false, // make sure it can't be overwritten
      content: 'bla bla bla'
      show: {
         ready: true // make sure it show on first mouseover
      }
   })
```

Comment: I have added the `overwrite` and `show` properties as you described above. No luck so far though :-(